# Why I can't use printk() to print string to the console

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am trying to add some system interface made by myself to Linux-0.11 and using bochs to debug the interface.But I have found two strange things.
Here is my code.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <asm/segment.h>
char msg[24] = {0};//23 characters + ’\0' = 24
int sys_iam(const char* name)
/***
 * function : put the content in name(address) to msg, and the length of it should be no longer than 23  
 * return：the number of character which is copied
 ***/
{
    printk("Sys_iam is running\n");
    int i;
    //store the data temporarily
    char buf[25] = {0};
    for(i = 0;i<25;i++){
        buf[i] = get_fs_byte(name + i);
        if(buf[i] == '\0')break;
    }
    int len = i;
    //if the length is bigger than 23
    if(len > 23){
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;//set the errno to ENIVAL，return -1
    }
    //int j;
    int j;
    for(j = 0;j<len;j++){
        msg[j] = buf[j];
    }
    msg[len] = '\0';
    printk("len:%d\n", len);
    //printk("buflen:%d\n",strlen(buf));
    printk("buf:%s\n", buf);
    printk("msglen:%d\n",strlen(msg));
    printk("msg:%s\n", msg);
    return len;
}
```

I found the msg's len is 0, and the buf and msg can't be shown on console.
[The screenshot of console withou strlen(buf)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JydIu.png)

But when I add the code "printk("buflen:%s",strlen(buf));",I found the msglen is 5, and I can see buf on the console buf still can't see msg.
Here is the code(I just add one line):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <asm/segment.h>
char msg[24] = {0};//23 characters + ’\0' = 24
int sys_iam(const char* name)
/***
 * function : put the content in name(address) to msg, and the length of it should be no longer than 23  
 * return：the number of character which is copied
 ***/
{
    printk("Sys_iam is running\n");
    int i;
    //store the data temporarily
    char buf[25] = {0};
    for(i = 0;i<25;i++){
        buf[i] = get_fs_byte(name + i);
        if(buf[i] == '\0')break;
    }
    int len = i;
    //if the length is bigger than 23
    if(len > 23){
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;//set the errno to ENIVAL，return -1
    }
    //int j;
    int j;
    for(j = 0;j<len;j++){
        msg[j] = buf[j];
    }
    msg[len] = '\0';
    printk("len:%d\n", len);
    printk("buflen:%d\n",strlen(buf));
    printk("buf:%s\n", buf);
    printk("msglen:%d\n",strlen(msg));
    printk("msg:%s\n", msg);
    return len;
}
```

And this is the things on the console:

[The screenshot of console with strlen(buf)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtNWB.png)

So I am confused with these two things:

1.why I can't see msg on the console

2.Why the msg len is 5(which is argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JydIu.png)'s len) when I add
strlen(buf)

Here is the test code iam.c:

```
#define __LIBRARY__
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

_syscall1(int, iam, const char*, name);
int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    iam(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank for your help sincerely!

Comment: Does `cat /proc/kmsg` show up your logs?

Comment: I doubt linux-0.11 had proc in it. :-) Having said that, does not tweaking such an old software belongs to https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: You mentioned adding `printk("buflen:%s",strlen(buf));`. That's incorrect (and wouldn't have printed `5`, so I presume it's not what you really tried). `%s` expects a `char*`; `strlen(buf)` is of type `size_t`. The correct format for `size_t` since C99 is `%zu`; I don't know whether the ancient `printk` you're using supports that. If not, I'd cast to `unsigned long` and use `%lu`.

Comment: @ZosoI have tried cat /proc/kmsg, but it shows that `No such file or  directory`. And I can't find the cmd to check log in Linux-0.11.@oakad Thank you for your advice, I will ask question again.@Keith Sorry, it's my mistake, and I have used %d instead of %s. But my gcc in Linux-0.11 use the version of C90.